# strip_tags in get_the content

Tags: the-content

So, I tried to strip all the html tags in a string but I can't get it to work.

This is my code snippet

```
$content = get_the_content();                                                                                                               
$content = preg_replace("/<embed[^>]+\>/i", "(embed) ", $content);                                                                                                                      
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);                                                                                                              
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);                                                                                                             
echo wp_strip_all_tags($content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = get_the_content();
// regex (fixed) replacing '<embed>' with '(embed )'
$content = preg_replace("/<embed?[^>]+>/i", "(embed) ", $content);
// remove all tags
$content = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
echo $content;
```

**Edited according to the first comment:**

What you are trying to remove are not tags, these are HTML character entities. E. g., `<p>` was converted to `&lt;p&gt;` by WordPress when you've saved the content in the visual editor.

You have two choices:

1. edit the content in the built-in text editor to remove those entities (switch the editor from *Visual* to *HTML* mode);
2. use different regexes to remove entities after the post was fetched.

For example (not tested, but you have the idea):

```
$content = preg_replace("/&lt;embed?[.]+&gt/i", "(embed) ", $content);
$content = preg_replace("/&lt;[.]+&gt/i", "", $content);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. To be honest, I tried almost every trick in the book, tags still show up. For Example : https://www.mygadgeto.com/wpmig/index.php/gadget/h20-ninja-full-face-snorkeling-mask/ (Regarding the description tab)

Comment: @KonstantinosKoletsas, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strip all tags, you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). 
Small code example:

```
$content      = get_the_content();
$cleaned      = strip_tags($content, '<br>'); //keeps newlines
$superCleaned = strip_tags($content); //No HTML Tags
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the first function I worked with without a result.

Comment: I am not sure @KonstantinosKoletsas. When using `strip_tags`, you are still having tags in your code?